# Hotkey Tips in Menu: Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, menu, menuitem, hotkeys

**Language**: C++

**Development Environment**: Microsoft Visual C++

**Libraries Used**: MFC

**Problem**: Should be a fairly simple question. I'm trying to add in hotkey key-combinations to my menu for various items (Save, Open, etc.). Usually a menu will say something like "Save" (left-justified) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd> (right-justified). How do I accomplish this? Do I just use spaces in my caption, or is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: @Patryk - please don't do minor edits to questions.  If you are going to edit a post, make sure you’re substantively improving it.  See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116660

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Alright, sorry for that - I didn't know. I thought it's a good idea just to improve the questions/answers at least a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tab character to separate the command text from the hotkey text:

```
&Open...\tCtrl+O
```

(Note that this only affects the text of the menu - to actually make the hotkey work, you need to add it to your accelerator table.)